# C# created variables before if

Tags: c#

I want to write a code that every 25 times, the program should go back to  run `Part_1_code` as follow. Here is problem that, `Part_2_code` has a lot of variables created in the `Part_1_code`, so following code is not allowed, but we couldn't not declare those variables at the beginning, since they are all anonymous type (read-only) so how to solve it? I do not wish to create a new class.

```
int Count = 1;
foreach (DateTime Date in TestDate)
{
    if(Count == 1 || Count == 25){
        Part_1_code;
        Count = 1;
    }

    Pair_2_code;

    Count++;                
}
```

Comment: So, just so I understand this; `Part_2_Code` uses variables created by `Part_1_Code`?

Comment: One way would be to create some kind of Context object, populate it and pass it between the methods. You say (do not create new class), why don't you want to create a new class?

Comment: That's why people always tell you to avoid side effects... Can you try to split `Part_1_code` into two methods? One that declares and initializes stuff and another one that only performs the real action?

Comment: Similar to @Milney's idea, why don't you turn Part_1_code and Pair_2_code into functions? That way you can pass parameters into Pair_2_code, which you can get from Part_1_code and assign to the foreach loops's local memory.

Comment: @ Jamiec Yes...how to solve

Comment: Why exactly can't you define your variables before the cycle or before the 'if' ? Could you write an example of part_1_code?

Comment: @user6703592 Try to put the code from `Part_1_code` into two methods. One that initializes stuff and calls the other method (call it `Part_1_code_full` for example) and one that only performs the actions (`Part_1_code_actions` for example). In your above code sample, call `Part_1_code_actions`.

Comment: But `Part_1_code` is a very long code, it is very strange to write a code two times almost same.

Comment: Now here's an X-Y question if ever I saw one...

Comment: It would also be slightly more precise to say you execute your code every 24 times, the way it's written (it runs part "1" on iterations 1, 25, 49, 73, etc.). Using 1-based indexing in C-like languages is rather awkward, if you started from `0`, it would probably work the way you think it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables which need to be accessible in a certain scope must also be defined in that scope, or a parent (outer) scope. Apart from that, it might be simpler to use a plain `for` loop in this case, combined with a module (`%`) operator.

It would also be slightly more precise to say you execute your "specific" code every 24 times, the way it's written. Using 1-based indexing in C-like languages is rather awkward.

```
for (var count = 0; count < TestDates.Count; count++)
{
    var date = TestDates[count];

    SomeStuff stuff = null;
    if (count % 24 == 0)
    {
        // runs on 0, 24, 48, ...
        stuff = new SomeStuff();
    }

    // runs on each iteration, 'stuff' will be non-null only if 
    // previous part was executed.
}
```

You can also extract these branches into methods, and pass the shared state as a parameter:

```
// decide whether this should be outside the loop 
// (i.e. keep the state from previous iterations),
// or declared within the `for` loop
var state = new SharedState();

for (var count = 0; count < TestDates.Count; count++)
{
    var date = TestDates[count];
    if (count % 24 == 0)
    {
        // runs on 0, 24, 48, ...
        ProcessPart1(state);
    }

    // runs on each iteration
    ProcessPart2(state);
}
```

Where `SharedState` contains any data you need to share between these branches:

```
class SharedState
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

If your `ProcessPart1` method returns a value, you can even use a ternary operator to simplify the code:

```
for (var count = 0; count < TestDates.Count; count++)
{
    var date = TestDates[count];

    // runs on 0, 24, 48, ...
    var someData = (count % 24 == 0) ? Process1(date) : null;

    // runs on each iteration
    Process2(someData);
}
```

One option is to make state a private field in the parent class, but a common rule of thumb is to try to limit scope of your variables as much as possible.

Of course, if you posted some actual code which executes in these two branches, it could perhaps be possible to refactor the code slightly better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens if you're if  doesn't run
Then all the variables inside would be null.

You can't use variables out of scope.
You could create variables before if
and add the value in your if

```
int Count = 1;
        foreach (DateTime Date in TestDate)
        {
            int someVariable;
            if(Count == 1 or Count == 25){
                Part_1_code that set the somevariable value;
                Count = 1;
            }


            Pair_2_code that can access someVariable;

            Count++;                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems pretty straightforward, `Part_1_Code` can just be a function which returns your data.

```
int Count = 1;
Part1Result p1 = null;
foreach (DateTime Date in TestDate)
{
    if(Count == 1 or Count == 25){
        p1 = Part_1_code();
        Count = 1;
    }

     //Part_2_code
     //use variable p1 here - its the results from Part1Code
     Count++;                
}
```

elsewhere

```
public Part1Result Part_1_code()
{
     return new Part1Result(){ SomeData = "foo" };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize an anonymous type by using a dummy value:

```
var Count = 1;
var someAnonymous = new {Date = new DateTime(), Count = 0}; // init with dummy values
foreach (DateTime Date in TestDate)
{

    if(Count == 1 || Count == 25){
        // Part_1_code
        Count = 1;
    }

    // Part_2_code

    Count++;                
}
```

Anonymous types are read-only, you cannot change the values of their properties, but you can replace the whole variable by assigning it again without changing any property.